# Как убрать класс у элемента при клике на другой jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Надо убрать класс `active-item-li` у `li` по нажатию на кнопку `close-item-li`.

Этих элементов много, я подозреваю что в этом и проблема.

По идеи тут добавляется класс, что бы увеличить элемент по нажатию на него, там появится кнопка с `Х`, нажав на который можно удалить класс и вернуть всё исходное положение.

Вот моё нерабочее решение:

```
let someDiv = $('.type-product');

someDiv.on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active-item-li');
});

$('close-item-li').on('click' , function () {
    someDiv.removeClass('active-item-li');
});
```

HTML:

```
<li class="type-product active-item-li">

  <button class="close-item-li">x</button>

  <a href="#" class="link">ссылка</a>    
  
  <a>ссылка</a>  

</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае Вам достаточно найти родительский элемент кнопки и удалить у него нужный класс:

```js
$(".close-item-li").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass("active-item-li")
})
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.active-item-li {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="type-product active-item-li">
  <button class="close-item-li">x</button>
</li>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<li class="type-product active-item-li">
  <button class="close-item-li">x</button>
</li>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<li class="type-product active-item-li">
  <button class="close-item-li">x</button>
</li>
```

Comment: в примере всё работает, однако у меня почему то нет.

Comment: Может быть проблема в том, что у меня button находится в li? И когда я нажимаю на button, то одновременно нажимаю на li?